# How to edit code inside div from site?

Tags: javascript, php, include, administration

I am making an administration site and I have run in to a little problem...

How can I get from this code, a javascript var with name of that file?:

```
<div class="editable"><?php include 'myfile.php' ?></div>
```

In this case `myfile.php`.

Here is rest of my related code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["name"] == "administrator")
    {
        ?>
        <script language="javascript">
        function copytext() {
            var CopiedText = $(".editable").html();
            var SourceFileName = euhm....;
            alert (SourceFileName);
            if (CopiedText.indexOf("'") === -1) 
            {
                alert (CopiedText);
                $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "code.php",
                    data: { CopiedText : CopiedText, SourceFileName : SourceFileName },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("ajax 3 error");
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert (response);
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("There can not be ( ' ) in the text!");
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}?>
```

And the code.php:

```
<?php
$texttowrite = $_POST['CopiedText'];
$originalfile = $_POST['SourceFileName'];
echo "$texttowrite";
file_put_contents ($originalfile, $texttowrite);?>
```

I am an absolute newbie so I would really appreciate any advice. Also I am not native english speaker, so I am sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Even in an administrative interface, allowing users to edit code directly in their browser, and having those changed propagate to the server are a seriously bad idea.

Comment: Well...why? My "boss" asked for exactly something like this and he knows basics of HTML. What do you think would be better idea to do something like this? Thanks a lot for replay.

Comment: For starters, code should be under source control, check out [git](http://git-scm.com/). Second, your "boss" might know the basics of HTML, but if he makes mistakes. Mistakes you won't be able to rewind easily. Not to mention that your "boss" will not be your "boss" for ever, and the "boss" the replaces him might not know HTML as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look on Git. And this is personal website so there will not be another administrator and my "boss" is also my friend and I know him for a some time so I think there should not be problems that you mentioned there.

Comment: What I need to know, is that code OK? It works (except that SourceFileName var), but I do not know if it is correct or can not be done better? And if my "boss" will add just <p>, <h1> and similar, can he mess something so hard? Thank you very much for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're attempting to let a person change a site's code is really insecure AND very inefficient. The problem's not about trusting the user. These kind of security holes can be exploited by *outsiders* if they ever gain secret access to the page.

Anyway, as an alternative I'd suggest a version-controlling system such as Git/SVN where your changes are track-able and no security issues will arise. Also, it would be much easier to use.